# DBContext multi-threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, loops, dbcontext

I have a website I've built in VS2010 which is using MVC3 (Razor)

I use DBContexts to access the datbase, my connection string is:

```
<add name="SystemDBContext"
connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|System.sdf"
providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

I want to have a game loop so I've started a new thread in Application_Start which loops and accesses the database using the DBContext.

What seems to be happening is that the loop uses the DBContext and locks the db file, and then whenever you try to make changes from the DBContext on the website itself, the file is in use.

It's not when I declare DBContext, it happens whenever I try to use the DBContext to perform a search or update of some sort.

Here's my Global.asax

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...
        Manager m = new Manager();
        Thread t = new Thread(m.Start);
        t.Start();
    }
```

Part of one of my controllers:

```
public class myController : Controller
{
    private SystemDBContext db = new SystemDBContext();


    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        var engines = db.Engines.Include(e => e.state);
        return View(engines.ToList());
    }
    ...
```

And my loop looks something like this:

```
public class Manager
{
    public void Start()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            SystemDBContext db = new SystemDBContext();
            var query = from ...
        }
        ...
```

What is the best practice for doing this? I've been thinking of Singletons, Locks or Synclocks, adjusting the connection string to allow multiple attaches to the database file, or having my loop request a web page that does the update.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the loop thread create its DBContext once and hangs on to it, or does it just create one when needed for a specific unit of work? Can you show the code where that DBContext is created?

Comment: I forgot to include it in the original post, I've put it in now. The loop repeatedly poles the DB using a new Context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What seems to be happening is that the loop uses the DBContext and locks the db file, and then 
>   whenever you try to make changes from the DBContext on the website itself, the file is in use.

Back to reading the documentation? The part where it says WinCE is NOT A SERVER FOR MULTIPLE THREADS. Use SQL Server instead - [Express is free](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26729). CE is for limited scalability items, single threaded access.

> What is the best practice for doing this?

Use a proper database server. CE is HEAVILY problematic, especially if you start / stop the database engine all the time, which results into a LOT of inefficient disc access.

SQL Server is done for exactly that and as I said - Express is cheap.

Comment: Good catch noticing SqlServerCe.4.0 in the connection string.

Comment: Also the size limits of SQL Express are less restrictive than CE. (10GB vs 4GB respectively)

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. I have SQL Express 10.0.5500 setup on my machine and have used it in the past. If I change my connection string then the CF approach should build the database, correct? I tried the following

    <add name="SystemDBContext" 
         connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=System;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

But got an error during runtime, it couldn't connect to SQL Server.

Comment: Well, then properly set it up properly - sorry, not doing express so much ;)

Comment: I wound up going with this
<add name="SystemDBContext" 
         connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=System;Integrated Security=True;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
It seems to have created my database OK. I'm going to see if I can force a multithreaded access and see if it works.